# How to set state of an object within a list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I set the state of the list here?
I have used `setList` multiple ways and have not been successful...

`const [list, setList] = useState([{userName: name, itemList: []}])`

This state is set during the `handleSubmit` as below:

```js
const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let newName = name
  let allTasks = task
  let newTask = taskItem
  setTask([...task, newTask])
  console.log(allTasks)
        
  const newListObj= {
    id: new Date().getTime().toString(),
    userName: newName
  }
  setList([...list, newListObj])
  console.log(list)
  setIsEditing(false)
  setList({ userName: '', itemList: [] })
  setName('')
}
```

No matter what I do, I'm not able to see the `list` state values updated. The data is being passed along other states just fine.

Comment: Why do you call `setList` in the end passing `{ userName: '', itemList: [] }`?

Comment: @IvanReshetnikov Completely missed that!! That was resetting every state I set. Thanks for pointing it out...